# Storing incoming files in a directory in Express JS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to configure ExpressJS to accept an incoming XML file for parsing. I have read that bodyParser has deprecated support for xml and I simply can't figure out how to make my application accept an incoming xml and store it.

Since the external server requires my site to be live to send the xml file, I have been building using local testing techniques. Namely, I created an upload form that will successfully do what I want it to do, upload an xml file and store it targeting a url.

When I push these changes to the server and target the same URL with the external server, the xml file gets lost in transit and is never stored.

Am I wrong in assuming that this POST coming from another server would automatically get placed into the faxes directory given this line?

In my Express Configuration

```
app.use(express.bodyParser( { keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, '/faxes')}));
```

Comment: Which version of express are you using ?

Comment: I am using express 4. I am reading up on Formidable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In express.js v 3+ the file upload middleware  is removed you have to handle your file with your own .

Here is an example of [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to upload file in a custom url path

```
var formidable = require('formidable')

app.post('/xmlpath' ,req, res, next){

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) { 

    var tempFilePath = files.file['path'],
        userFileName  = files.file['name'],
        contentType   = files.file['type'];

    // then read your file with fs 
    // you can also move your file to another location with fs 
    // by default file will be place to tempFilePath


     fs.readFile( tempFilePath, function(err, file_buffer){

    // do what you want to do with your file 
});
});
});
```

Comment: I wrote this into the receive-file function and I am getting an error.  var tempFilePath = files.file['path'],TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Comment: could you share the piece of code you are using to send the file ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You see, I am integrating eFax into our application. The eFax server sends an XML file and their documentation is less than adequate. Also their tool for sending 'Test Faxes' is extremely minimal and does not allow you to do anything except send a sample XML document to a targeted URL.

Comment: Ohh then did it worked for you ? I am using this piece of code in my angularjs based web app and its working fine .

Comment: I gave you the answer because ultimately Formidable fixed my Problem. The bodyParser was causing problems with Formidable which is why I couldn't upload. I removed the bodyParser and now all things work perfectly. Thank you for your guidance.